# I2C with 1.8V levels without level shifters?

Tags: i2c, level-shifting

I have problems detecting an MPU-6050 I2C device on the Intel Edison Mini breakout board (it only supports 1.8V levels). According to the [thread here](https://communities.intel.com/thread/60853?start=0&tstart=0), it might be possible to get the sensor working with 1.8V levels:

> "The MPU-6050 also supports different supply (VDD) and I/O interface
>   (VLOGIC) voltages.  If your board allows you to make separate
>   connections to VDD (on pin 13) and VLOGIC (on pin 8), leave VDD on
>   3.3V and connect VLOGIC to 1.8V.  Connect the pull-up resistors on SDA and SCL to 1.8V.  The MPU-6050 will then speak I2C directly at 1.8V,
>   eliminating the need for a discrete level shifter."

Anyone can suggest how this setup might work (i.e. make a drawing) ?

Thanks!

Comment: You understand that I2C uses OD outputs and is therefore not actively driven high, right?

Comment: hmm.. not having too much experience with this, when on arduino, it could attach the sensor SDA and SCL to the board, now on the edison nothing happens

Comment: so, i am feeling i miss something, but not sure if it is a circuit, or just making the wrong connections between pins.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The I²C bus pullups and VLOCGIC on the MPU chip must be connected to the 1.8 Volt rail:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fPK7Yk.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The MPU-6050 still needs 3.3 Volts on its VDD pin. Note that this will only work if your MPU-6050 module has not connected VLOGIC to VDD in any way on the PCB.

Comment: thanks! just curious, do you see a chance to level shift the edison 1.8V bus to the 3.3V for this MPU6050 board? http://301o583r8shhildde3s0vcnh.wpengine.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/mpu6050.png

Comment: There are specialized I²C level shifter ICs. Your board would need those, as VLOGIC is connected to 3V3 VDD rail.

Comment: just for reference, I saw the board example: https://www.sparkfun.com/products/13034